# creating a solr core on windows machine gives "acess is denied" error

Tags: windows, solr

i am trying to create a solr core on windows machine through command prompt, i have used the following command

```
solr -c movie
```

but it gives me an "access is denied" error
I checked the permission of bin folder and set it to read write for all the users. 
but still i get the same error.

[image]

Comment: Screen shot is missing

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1pMiN.png

Answer (score 0):

i changed the file permission of the solr folder to 777 and the error was not there anymore